# Why is there a default id field in factory Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, factory

I have a Question Factory created for my Question model. I don't have any id field in the question model, but I don't understand where the factory is creating one.

**Factory**

```php
/* @var $factory \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory */

use App\Question;use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Question::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'qid' => $faker->name,
        'question' => $faker->sentence
    ];
});
```

The output of factory in Tinker.

```
Psy Shell v0.9.9 (PHP 7.2.19 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> factory('App\Question')->create();
=> App\Question {#3001
     qid: "Bell Schamberger",
     question: "Consequatur debitis est nemo.",
     updated_at: "2019-07-07 15:08:27",
     created_at: "2019-07-07 15:08:27",
     id: 0,
   }
```

Comment: There is nothing on migration also  ?

Answer (score 2):

Eloquent assumes that each table has a primarry key named 'id'

you can override this (eg in you model) like this:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'youre_pk_field';
```